# C++ - using base class as template parameter

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I'd like my template function to accept as an argument only a class that inherits from a base class. I think a code snippet explains it better.

```cpp
class Base
{
    // Some magic
}

class Derived : public Base
{
    // Even more magic
}

class Foo
{}

// Is it possible to tell template to accept only classes derived from Base?
template<class T>
do_something(T obj)
{
    // Perform some dark magic incantations on obj
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    Derived derived;
    do_something<Derived>(derived); // Normal
    do_something<Foo>(foo); // Compilation error if I understand templates correctly
}
```

Comment: Can you use C++20?

Comment: @AndyG C++ 17 only I suppose

Comment: Should `do_something` allow instances of `Base` itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-C++20 you can use `enable_if` coupled with checking `is_base_of`:

```
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Base, T> && !std::is_same_v<Base, T>, int> = 0>
void do_something(T obj)
{
    // Perform some dark magic incantations on obj
}
```

Note that I've explicitly disallowed the type to be an instance of `Base` (because `is_base_of` considers a type to be a base of itself). If you want to allow instances of `Base`, then remove `&& !std::is_same_v<Base, T>`

#### [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vmjoMBeOEmtPuF8z)

---

In C++20 we can almost directly translate our `enable_if` into a `requires` expression:

```
template<class T>
requires (std::is_base_of_v<Base, T> && !std::is_same_v<Base, T>)
void do_something(T obj)
{
   // ...
}
```

#### [Concepts Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/diWzM1ufeqP5Rglo)

Or, if you want to allow instances of `Base`, you can use the built-in `derived_from` Concept:

```
template<class T>
requires std::derived_from<T, Base>
void do_something(T obj)
{
   // ...
}
```

#### [Concepts Demo 2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1ZSFL2TItImPJDQt)